# How can I assign a customisable mouse button to open Notification Center?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, macos, notifications

I want to set my mouse's customisable button to open Notification Centre on OS X Mountain Lion.

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! What make/model is your mouse and what driver software are you using? Are you talking about the scroll wheel button or a different button?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your mouse and driver software, your best bet would probably be to set a keyboard shortcut for Notification Center and program your mouse button to trigger that shortcut.

You can set up the shortcut in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Show Notification Center.
[image]

The setup for your mouse driver will vary, but on a Razer mouse you can assign the button to a Keyboard Function and type your shortcut.

[image]

Comment: USBOverdrive is great as a generic customisable mouse driver.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) paired with an Apple keyboard shortcut as shown:

[image: BTT Settings]
[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have customizable mouse software, you can write an AppleScript to perform the keystroke and then attach the mouse button to the script.

The script I used is:

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "N" using {command down, control down, option down, shift down}
```

You will have to adjust the keystroke and the modifier keys to suit whatever you set in the Keyboard Shortcuts preference pane.

Save the script as an application bundle, then stick it somewhere (I put it in `~/Library/Scripts`). Adjust your mouse button in System Preferences to open the application bundle.